# Looking for a very specific regex, between two dashes, after a dash

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a regex that will pull out information between two dashes, but after a dash has already existed.

```
I will list a few examples:

a = BRAND NAME - 34953 Some Information, PPF - 00003 - (3.355pz.) 300%
b = 893535 - MX LMESJFG - 01001 - ST2 | ls.33.dg - OK
c = 4539883 - AB05 - AG03J238B - | D.87.yes.4/3 - OK

What I want to pull out:
a = 00003
b = 01001
c = AG03J238B
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can stick to the base string functions here and use `split()` and `strip()`:

```py
a = "BRAND NAME - 34953 Some Information, PPF - 00003 - (3.355pz.) 300%"
match = a.split("-")[2].strip()
print(match)  # 00003
```

Comment: I tried this on a specific instance and it worked! However, when I put this into a for loop I keep getting an error that the index is out of range. How can I avoid this error while still incorporating the [2].

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by creating a try except when the values didn't make sense.

Comment: @JordanK Sorry for the late reply.  The way I would have handled it would be to check: `if len(a) - len(a.replace('-', '')) >= 2` ... if this assertion were true, then you could be certain that there are at least two dashes, and therefore accessing `[2]` won't crash.  The else condition could be some handler which logs or just otherwise ignores the input.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, but the following python regular expression should find all occurrences for each line of file (assuming your using python language).
Hope this works for you.  Not limited to string splits failures I don't think

```
import re
match = re.findall(r"(?=(-\s\w+\s-))", c)
print(match)
```

the (?=()) allows you to find overlapping issues, look up in the documents for look aheads and look behinds.
Good luck.

Comment: your very welcome and thanks for letting me know it worked for your situation.